# SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security conf

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

We have enabled 'XPCmdShellEnabled' on the database serve and we used command shell script in one of the SP which executes on daily job.

(Our Command shell script basically create the directory, create the file and dump the tem table data to csv file).

Issue: From past few days the daily job filing with the below error, before that it was working fine and nobody changed any configurations on server.

**SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell' search for 'xp_cmdshell' in SQL Server Books Online.**

(We have enabled 'XPCmdShellEnabled' = true on 'Surface Area Configuration'.

I have tried again by executing below query, and tried SP.

```
   sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
   RECONFIGURE
   sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1' 
   RECONFIGURE
```

But no luck..

Please let me know if anybody aware/faced of this similar type of issue and found solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Check for a server-level trigger that stops this configuration change.

Comment: Are you really on sql azure?  I thought cp_cmdshell was not supported there?

Comment: Assuming you're not on sql azure then, I'd suggest checking to see if facets/group policy might be overriding you.